# how to attach a file in email using shared hosting server?

Tags: asp.net, email-attachments

I want to attach a file dynamically and send it through mail. So can someone please let me know how can i send it with attachment.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: have you seen this **http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/asp-net-mvc-2-sending-email-fails/**

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code.

```
using System.Net.Mail;

private void SendEmail()
{
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    message.From = new MailAddress("YourEmailAddress@domain.com");
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("Recipient@domain.com"));
    message.Subject = "Subject";
    message.Body = "Email Message Body";

    // Add attachment
    string attachmentPath = Server.MapPath("~/AttachmentPath.jpg");
    message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachmentPath));

    // Connect to GoDaddy SMTP
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("relay-hosting.secureserver.net");
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Username","Password");
    smtp.Port = 25;
    smtp.EnableSsl = false;

    // Send the message
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: They would use relay-hosting.secureserver.net as it is what is used to send emails from our shared hosting accounts.  smtp.secureserver.net is used with our web based email accounts when using an email client.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this code

```
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("...");/:Adjust your adress
                mail.From = new MailAddress("your_email_address@gmail.com");
                mail.To.Add("to_address");
                mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
                mail.Body = "mail with attachment";

                System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
                attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("your attachment file");
                mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

                SmtpServer.Port = ..; //Replace with your port number
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```